# Bulk insert from .csv and update, insert and delete in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored procedure that will bulk insert data from a .csv into a table, but the procedure should not "insert duplicates". Some of the rows might already be in the table but some of the values might have changed, I guess an `UPSERT` would be good here, but what about deleting records that already exist in the table but don't exist in the .csv?

The end goal is exactly the same as wiping the entire table and inserting all the .csv data into it, but as the .csv has millions of records and only a few hundred of them change from time to time, I assume "updating" the table is faster than wiping it.

```
DECLARE @ssql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'BULK INSERT gl_ip_range FROM ''' 
  + @psTempFilePath 
  + 
''' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR ='','', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'', FORMAT =''CSV'', FIRSTROW =2 )' 
;
```

The code above is what I currently use together with clearing the table prior to the insert.

Will clearing the table and inserting the millions of records be faster than doing what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: BULK INSERT just pushes everything in without filtering. If you use OPENROWSET instead, you can select from it, and do things like distinct operations, etc. on the way in.

Comment: No one can tell you if <option A> is faster than <option B> without knowing anything about your table, how the rows it contains changes over time, and some idea of the number of rows that need to be updated/inserted/deleted with each import. The best advice is to implement both and compare the results. You may not have the resources for that, so you simply need to evaluate the options and guess based on experience and your own estimates.